# Now we’re talking!

Tags: meaning

In [*Inside Out*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside_Out_(2015_film)), Joy says:

> Now we're talking! Let's go get our stuff from the moving van!

What does *Now we're talking!* mean?

Is it slang meaning something special?

Answer (score 5):

It is informal/slang speech meaning "I enthusiastically agree with what you have said" or "I enthusiastically like the topic that you mentioned"

For example:

A:"Let's go to the beach."

B:"Now we're talking, I'll get my bucket and spade."

or

A:"And then the next day we went to the beach."

B:"Now we're talking, I love the beach."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's an expression that belongs to the informal register of the English language. This is an offshoot of the equally common phrase [**now you're talking!**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/now+you%27re+talking!). As for the meaning, you say *now we're talking* when you want to tell your listener that you really like what you hear. For example:

> — I'm gonna pay you fifteen bucks an hour for this job. How's that sound to you?
>   — **Now we're talking!** I would love to do this job!